# How to test getter that returns a list of custom objects?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Ok so lets say we have the following simple class:

```
 public class Employees{


        List<Person> personsList;
        private int numberOfEmployees;

        public void Employees(){

        //constructor

        }

        //getters & setters

        public List<Person> getPersons(){
            return personsList;
        }

          public void addNewEmployee(Person person){

        this.personsList.add(person);

    }

    }
```

And i want to test the getter that returns a list of Person objects(using mockito)

I am doing something like:

```
@Test
public void getPersonsTest() throws Exception{
    Employees.addNewEmployee(employee); //where employee is a mocked object

    assertEquals(Employees.getPersons(),WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE??);


}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your getPersons() is a void method. Are you sure of the posted code ?

Comment: yea my bad. gonna fix it fast.

Comment: .... and being called in a static manner -- Please up your game as this is (to be blunt) very sloppy code. If you have a serious question, please post serious, *real* code.

Comment: It's not a good use of time to test getter and setter methods.  Spend your time testing methods that actually contain some kind of logic instead.  And even if you're determined to test the getter, mockito is not something you should be using to do so.

Comment: Mockito or pure Junit, i still dont get how this should be tested

Comment: Short answer - it shouldn't.  Don't test getters.  But you can include getters in your tests of other methods.  Here, you might want to test `addNewEmployee`, and my answer describes how you might do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test that a single person can be added to your list, you could do something like this.  Since all the classes are "value classes", there's no point in using Mockito.

```
@Test
public void singleEmployeeAddedToList() throws Exception{
    Employees toTest = new Employees();
    Person testSubject = new Person("John", "Smith");
    toTest.addNewEmployee(testSubject);

    assertEquals(Collections.singletonList(testSubject), toTest.getPersons());
}
```

Note that in a JUnit assert, the expected result comes first, followed by the result that you're trying to check.  If you get it wrong way round, the error messages make no sense when the assertion fails.

Note that this is really more of a test of `addNewEmployee` than of `getPersons`.